# How to proof that $\angle CTP = \angle CBP+ \angle BCN$?

Tags: geometry

How do you proof that $\angle CTP = \angle CBP+ \angle BCN$ ? 
Please check the image below:

[image: enter the great image description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. angles in a triangle sum to 180 degrees
2. supplementary angles sum to 180 degrees

Answer (score 1):

$\angle CTP=\angle BTN=180^\circ-\angle PTN=180^\circ-\angle CTB=\angle CBT+\angle TCB = \angle CBP + \angle BCN$